# MongoDB $project filtered value from documents inside array inside a document

Tags: mongodb

I have documents that is similar to the below format.

```json
{
    "_id" : BinData(3, "hwEAAF0GirrTLooAVgAAEw=="),
    "Traits" : {
        "Components" : [
            {
                "ComponentId" : "BIOS_9",
                "ComponentType" : "software",
                "Description" : "BIOS at Memory Address: 0xf",
            },
            {
                "ComponentId" : "MBR_5",
                "ComponentType" : "software",
                "Description" : "MBR at Disk Address: 0x0",
            },
            {
                "ComponentId" : "Bootloader_Disk",
                "ComponentType" : "software",
                "Description" : "Bootloader at Disk Address: 0x2",
            },
            {
                "ComponentId" : "LinuxOS_X",
                "ComponentType" : "module",
                "Description" : "Ali Linux OS",
            },
            {
                "ComponentId" : "Platform_6",
                "ComponentType" : "module",
                "Description" : "Platform & market",
            },
            {
                "ComponentId" : "Legends__12345",
                "ComponentType" : "module",
                "Description" : "Installed module",
            }
        ]
    },
    "TrackerId" : "GEN7_3",
    "Action" : "Profile"
}
```

I need to display a resulting document like below. Filtering with `"ComponentType" : "module"` and `"Description" : "Installed module"`.

```json
{
    "TrackerId" : "GEN7_3",
    "Action" : "Profile",
    "ComponentId" : "Legends__12345"
}
```

I have tried to use aggregation with Match, Unwind, Project with filter but the `"ComponentId" : "Legends__12345"` still shows as nested value.

Comment: Can you share the query you have so far?  It would be much easier to tweak an already existing pipeline than to create one from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
db.example.aggregate( [
  {
    $unwind:
      {
        path: "$Traits.Components",
      },
  },
  {
    $match:
      {
        "Traits.Components.ComponentType":
          "module",
        "Traits.Components.Description":
          "Installed module",
      },
  },
  {
    $project:
      {
        _id: 0,
        TrackerId: 1,
        Action: 1,
        ComponentId:
          "$Traits.Components.ComponentId",
      },
  },
]
)
```

[Try Here](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/Iz1kRleM207)

which gives o/p as

```js
 
 { 
  TrackerId: 'GEN7_3',
  Action: 'Profile',
  ComponentId: 'Legends__12345'
 }
```